# How to fire selectionChange event on an Angular Material MatSelect from test code

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-test

I have a Component which embeds an Angular Material `MatSelect` element.

In a test that I am writing, I need to simulate the selection of a certain option and make sure that the `selectionChange` Observable associated to that `MatSelect` element actually fires.

So far my code is

```
const mySelect: MatSelect = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('#mySelect');
mySelect.value = 'new value';
```

But unfortunately this is not making the `mySelect.selectionChange` notify, and therefore my test work. Any idea on how this could be performed is very welcome.

Answer (score 6):

I would simply access the `MatSelect` in the component you want to test via `@ViewChild` so you can easily use it in your unit test.

```
/** For testing purposes */
@ViewChild(MatSelect) public matSelect: MatSelect;
```

And in your test I would select the desired option via `_selectViaInteraction()`, this simulates that the option was selected by the user.

```
it('test selectionChange', () => {    
  // make sure the mat-select has the expected mat-options
  const options: MatOption[] = component.matSelect.options.toArray();
  expect(options.length).toBe(3);
  expect(options[0].viewValue).toBe('Steak');
  expect(options[1].viewValue).toBe('Pizza');
  expect(options[2].viewValue).toBe('Tacos');

  // set up a spy on the function that will be invoked via selectionChange
  const spy = spyOn(component, 'onChange').and.callThrough();
  expect(spy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

  // select the option
  options[1]._selectViaInteraction();
  fixture.detectChanges();

  // selectionChange was called and the option is now selected    
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(options[1].selected).toBe(true);
});
```

> You can find a stackblitz
>   [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jasmine-blitz-qyxyni?file=app%2Fdummy%2Fdummy.component.spec.ts).

Answer (score 5):

A simple solution is

```
it('should take the dropdown value and show data ', () => {
let event = {value:25};
debugElement
.query(By.css('.mat-select'))
.triggerEventHandler('selectionChange',event);
fixture.detectChanges();
expect(component.generalLedgerRequest.pageSize).toBe(25);
});
```

Comment: Best solution. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

To get the `MatSelect` instance, you have to use the `DebugElement` on the fixture and access the directive using `By.directive`:

```
const mySelect = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(MatSelect));
mySelect.componentInstance.value = 'new value';
```