# Angular Jasmine FormControl Unit Test valueChanges

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I want to unit test my following method:

```js
this.boxValue = '';

subscribeToFilterChanges(): void {
  this.filterBox.valueChanges
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        if (data) {
          this.boxValue = data.trim().toLowerCase();
        }
      }
    );
}
```

filterBox is a FormControl:

```js
filterBox = new FormControl('');
```

HTML is:

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="standard">
  <input matInput [formControl]="filterBox"
        id="filterBox-input">
</mat-form-field>
```

I've written the unit test as:

```js
it('verify filter changes', () => { 
  let filterBoxInput = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#filterBox-input'));
  filterBoxInput.nativeElement.value = 'dummy';
  filterBoxInput.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
  fixture.detectChanges();
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    expect(component.boxValue).toBe('dummy1');
  });
});
```

This test should fail, but still it is showing as passed, even though incorrect value is specified in .toBe()

What could be the issue?

I referred to [Angular Testing: FormControl valueChanges Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51910630/angular-testing-formcontrol-valuechanges-observable)

Comment: You shouldn't need the `fixture.whenStable().then(` part. Reactive forms are synchronous. If you really want to keep it, then return that promise, or use `it('...', async(() => { ... }));`

Comment: @JBNizet I just want to verify the value of boxValue. I don't need the `fixture.whenStable()` specifically. How can I do it in other ways?

Comment: Well, as I said, remove it. Check the value right after you've called detectChanges(), without wrapping the check into a whenStable().then() callback. `fixture.detectChanges(); expect(component.boxValue).toBe('dummy1');`

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you. If the element is mat-select, then what should be in place of input in `new Event('input')` ?

Comment: I don't use angular material, but a mat-select is not a native HTML element, so it won't work with native events. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54474470/how-to-fire-selectionchange-event-on-an-angular-material-matselect-from-test-cod

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue here is that your component is not initialized properly at the time you're manipulating your `input`.

You must tell Angular to perform databing by calling `fixture.detectChanges();` right after creating component:

```
const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
fixture.detectChanges();
```

Also, as was mentioned in comments, `whenStable` is not needed here.

The completed test could look like:

```
it('verify filter changes', () => {
  const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  fixture.detectChanges();
  const component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
  let filterBoxInput = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#filterBox-input'));
  filterBoxInput.nativeElement.value = 'dummy';
  filterBoxInput.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(component.boxValue).toBe('dummy'); // should pass
});
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/ybBoYER6nvdRtMn0mnq0?test=true)**

Comment: Thank you. If the element is mat-select, then what should be in place of input in `new Event('input')` ?